# Strategy to identify the best coin with highest probability to produce head

Tags: probability, statistics

With `n` coins, each has a certain probability that generates a head. Using as small number of tosses as possible, how to find the coin that has the highest such probability?

As a concrete example, suppose 1 out of 100 coins has 0.50 head rate and the other 99 coins have 0.25 head rate. How can we efficiently find the coin that has 0.50 (i.e., what is the minimum number of tosses needed)? What about if there is a set of such coins, say, 10 coins with 0.50 head rate vs. 90 coins with 0.25 head rate?

Will the following process guarantee to find the best set?

```
1) toss each coin
2) keep the coin that has a head
3) keep any coin that has a tail with a certain rate and remove the others
4) repeat the procedure till a certain number of coins (e.g. 10) are left
```

If not, what does it give in the end?

Thanks!

Comment: No process can guarantee to find the best set in a finite number of tosses.  All you can do is find a process that has a certain probability of finding the best set, and you can look for the process that achieves that probability with the fewest tosses.

Comment: @RossMillikan: so what is such process with fewest tosses?

Comment: I don't have an answer to that.  I was just pointing out that you can't get a guarantee.  I suggest one approach below.  Another is just to flip each coin a certain number of times until you have enough data to assign it with a certain probability level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider another simple case: one with $N$ coins, $N-1$ of them normal coins, i.e., $P(H) = 1/2$, and the other coin completely rigged, i.e., $P(H)=1$.  Using Bayes' Theorem, one may deduce that the probability that a particular coin that has come up heads each time after $k$ flips is

$$P(\text{rigged}|H^k) = \frac{2^k}{2^k + N-1}$$

Let's say that we have pretty good chance of detecting the rigged coing when that probability is $> 1/2$.  Then, for example, with $N=100$ coins, we would need $k=7$ flips to have a better than 50/50 chance of detecting the rigged coin.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with just two coins, one that come up heads $\frac 12$ of the time and one that comes up heads $\frac 14$ of the time.  If we flip both of them and they come up the same, there is no information.  If one is heads and one tails, the heads is the $\frac 12$ coin with probability $\frac {\frac 12\cdot \frac 34}{\frac 12\cdot \frac 34+\frac 12 \cdot \frac 14}=\frac 34$.  Is that good enough for you?  If not, keep flipping.  Now if you record which coin comes up heads the times when they split, it is right $\frac 34$ of the time and wrong $\frac 14$ of the time.  You can use the binomial distribution to assess the chance that you are right and quit when you have enough data to be happy.  For example, if the first two times the coins split the same one comes up heads, it is now $\frac 9{10}$ that you have the correct one.